# Microsoft Excel - How do you auto-populate a formula in a column?

Tags: excel, automation, formula, excel-formula, excel-2010

Longevity, EmployeeID, StartDate, EndDate

I paste a bunch of data into the worksheet (cells B1-Dn), and I need the formula for A1-An (longevity) to automatically calculate the result for each employee that is entered.

I am using Microsoft Excel 2010.

Currently, the formula that I am using is:

```
=IF ( C1 , IF ( D1 , D1-C1 , TODAY()-C1 ) , "")
```

This works great, except that I have to manually add/remove cells with this formula in the A column to match the number of rows that are entered at any given time. This is very time-consuming, and difficult for Management to get their heads around when using this report. :)

Is there a way to say "Every row **with data in it**, gets THIS formula in column A"?

I've been researching this online, and found various answers. The most prominent answer was to use a drop-down-list with a default value, but I don't think that will work for a *default formula*.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how is it time consuming to fill-copy new rows in column A when you add data to the other columns? That should take a few seconds.

Comment: lol, hey, it's time-consuming when you have to do it multiple times daily for several different types of reports. The real issue is that nobody in their right-mind trusts Management to be able to handle even so much as a simple copy/paste operation, and Management won't believe the report is valid unless it is automated.

Comment: How are C1 and D1 working as the first argument in your `IF()` formulas?  Did you mean `C1<>""` instead?

Comment: You could just fill-copy column A way beyond the number of rows you have filled in in the other columns. With the way you wrote this formula, nothing will show in column A if there's no data in column C, but the formula will still be there, and a value will show up once the other columns are populated.

Comment: @Excellll if a cell contains data, it returns TRUE

Comment: @LowTechGeek, the only problem with fill-copying the column with extra breathing-room, is that this is potentially a very large set of data (tens of thousands of rows), and is ever-expanding with much unpredictibility. In order to be effective, we'd need to pre-fill the column so many rows ahead that the spreadsheed would grow in filesize hugely. Automation might be a bit of a headache in the short-term, but relieves a lot of long-term pain and ensures Management will always be happy with the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Data tables should help you out with ensuring that your formulas cover the entire range.

Step one:

Paste your data (no formulas)

Step two: Go to insert -> table you should get a dialog that looks something like

[image: Table dialog]

Now put your formula in the adjacent column. You will notice that the table formatting will automatically expand into where your formula is, and that the formula will auto copy to the bottom of your data set.

Step three:

Copy a larger dataset into the table.... you will notice that the formula copies down with your new extended data set.

Note that the table won't be resized if you paste a smaller dataset.

Comment: Once you have created a Table you can take advantage of the column names in the formula  `=IF([@StartDate],IF([@EndDate],[@EndDate]-[@StartDate],TODAY()-[@StartDate]),""),"")`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you need, then maybe you should try this.
In the every cell of column A (where you need the formula to be present if other columns contain data) add this formula :

```
=IF( AND( NOT(ISBLANK(B:B)),NOT(ISBLANK(C:C)),NOT(ISBLANK(D:D)) ),
     IF ( $C1 , IF ( $D1 , $D1-$C1 , TODAY()-$C1 ) , ""),"" )
```

To be more exact, you should add this formula in the A1 cell, and then auto fill all the A column.

Alternatively you could try setting the formula below in A1 cell and then auto fill the rest of the A column.

```
=IF( AND( NOT(ISBLANK(B1)),NOT(ISBLANK(C1)),NOT(ISBLANK(D1)) ),
     IF ( $C1 , IF ( $D1 , $D1-$C1 , TODAY()-$C1 ) , ""),"" )
```